# Best algorithm to get the path with less changes

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, path-finding

I am working with a subway network. I have to find some paths between A and B that respect some rules, for example, the fastest, shortest, etc... I know how to solve those, but one of  the rules is to find a path with less changes between lines, is there any algorithm used for that?

Comment: I don't see how that differs from the others. Couldn't you just, say, add some arbitrary delay in travel time to a change of trains and then use the `fastest` algorithm to find the path with less changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat a subway line as a node in graph, and connect two nodes by an edge if there is an intersection of two subway lines. Now, you can use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path.

Comment: Shortest path is found by Dijkstra but not sure how to find train changes while calculating closest nodes to each node.